# .append() in jQuery and IE8 has problems stopping from loading

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, javascript, stylesheet

I am working on a site that pulls a different stylesheet for use based on the current dimensions of the web browser.  I wrote the following line of code to add the stylesheet to the HTML:

```
$("head").append("<link href=\"/tta/front_page-lg.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\">");
```

Now the stylesheet loads alright, but in IE8, the favicon or IE icon stays in the 'loading' state or the blue ring if that is a clearer description.

I was wanting to know if there was another way of writing my code so that the browser would not stay in the "Loading" state.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: using single css is a bad choise

Answer (score 0):

Is it not just better to add just all CSS stylesheets in the head and make a body class? like so:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="stylesheet.css" media="all" type="text/css" />
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body id="useStyleSheetOne">
    <a id="test" href="#">I;m a link</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#test').click(function() {
                $('body').removeClass('useStyleSheetOne').addClass('useStyleSheetTwo');
            })
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

StyleSheet

## useStyleSheetOne a {

```
color: red;
font-size: 12px;
```

}

## useStyleSheetTwo a {

```
color: blue;
font-size: 32px;
```

}

Ok my second post so i can't get the stylesheet code in the code section :S.. For the stylesheetone and two is a #.

Grtz Sven

Comment: Your solution might work, but there are about a dozen or so classes to be switched.  I was just hoping it would be easier or better to do with a stylesheet switch.

Comment: I never did find a solution to this problem. I ended up using a script to dynamically resize the elements on the webpage in question by using the dimensions of the browser window as a reference point. Hopefully someone else could figure this out, but I couldn't.